# Redirecting user after jQuery $.post + sending a variable

Tags: php, ajax, string, jquery

I'm looking to redirect users to a new page once the form has been posted. However, I want to parse a variable to that new page as well. The variable is being returned by the PHP file.

```
    $("#ajaxquery").live( "click" , function(){
        var formdata = $(this).serialize(); 
        $.post( "includes/generate.php", formdata, function( data ) {
            $(".success").html(data);
        }); 
        return false;
    });
```

At the moment I can get the returned data from the PHP file to display on the .success div correctly but I can't get it to work using a redirect. This is what I'm trying:

```
window.location = "../download.php?site=" + html(data);
```

Also - is parsing the data in the URL the best approach for this? The data is just a unique ID which is used in download.php.

```
window.location = "../download.php?site="+data;
```

**EDIT:**

I tried the below code and it's working now but there's still another problem.

It's adding a double space between the = and the data for some reason? I can't see anything in the code that would cause this.

```
/download.php?site=  4e0928de075538c593fbdabb0c5ef2c3
```

Comment: I use this technique all the time. the issue relies with your php "echo". do you do something like `echo md5(stuff);`, and **no other** echo before that? using console.log(data) to check it is usually very helpfull

Comment: ^ yeah, I'm doing exactly that. Will see what console.log produces

Comment: Any whitespace before your opening `<?php` tag and/or after your closing `?>` tag (if there is one)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the problem with the spaces:

```
window.location.href="../download.php?site=" + data.replace(/^ +/,"");
```

This will strip out any opening spaces; I'm not sure where they're coming from.

Answer (score 3):

```
window.location = "../download.php?site=" + data;
```

should work.

Comment: yeah that works. I updated the OP with a new issue though. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you:

```
window.location.href = "../download.php?site=" + data;
```